# Optional URL segment when slug is existing

Tags: laravel, octobercms, slug

I would like to make a URL segment only part of the URL if a Slug is existing:

```
domain.com/category/:category/tag/:tag?
```

The "/tag/" segment should only be present if a `:tag` slug was given,
`domain.com/category/:category` should still be accessible if no `:tag` slug was given.

I tried with * wildcards but did not have any success - is this possible via the slug parameters or do I need to go via the controller of the page?

Comment: I am not sure, even you go via controller of page is that possible is a question. may be make 2 pages with url like `/category/:category` and `/category/:category/tag/:tag?` and use it conditionally when tag is available use tag page other wise simple one.

Comment: you can just make two standalone routes

Comment: Going two separate routes is a good suggestion - but you think it might not be possible with one route?

Comment: Why couldn't you just set all your links to include the tag in the url? I think you are over thinking this. No one types a full address now these days. I would just make the links like: `{% if link.tag %}/tag/{{ link.tag }}{% endif %}`. No one is going to type `stackoverflow.com/questions/58670529/optional-url-segment-when-slug-is-existing` in their web browser. They will get here by googling it and using SEO.